# Django Aws ClientError: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload my static files to Amazon S3 from my django project using boto3 and django-storages modules.

Here is the AWS S3 configurations in my **settings.py** file

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = "<public-key>"
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_ID = "<private-key>"

AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = "<bucket-name>"

STORAGES  = {
    # Media files (images) management
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "storages.backends.s3boto3.S3StaticStorage",
    },
    
    # CSS and JS file management
    "staticfiles": {
        "BACKEND": "storages.backends.s3boto3.S3StaticStorage",
    },
}

AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = f'{AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME}.s3.amazonaws.com'

AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
```

I have given AmazonS3FullAccess permission policy to the IAM user.

and here is my bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1706347165594",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1706347164281",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

previously I only gave PutObject action it didn't work. I was gettting the same error given below. Im using the **python manage.py collectstatic** command to upload to S3

```
You have requested to collect static files at the destination location as specified in your settings.

This will overwrite existing files!
Are you sure you want to do this?

Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel: yes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gajeet/Documents/Django/Django_ultimate/dev2/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/gajeet/Documents/Django/Django_ultimate/dev2/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/gajeet/Documents/Django/Django_ultimate/dev2/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/gajeet/Documents/Django/Django_ultimate/dev2/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 436, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/gajeet/Documents/Django/Django_ultimate/dev2/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 412, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/gajeet/Documents/Django/Django_ultimate/dev2/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 458, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/gajeet/Documents/Django/Django_ultimate/dev2/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 209, in handle
    collected = self.collect()
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/gajeet/Documents/Django/Django_ultimate/dev2/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 135, in collect
    handler(path, prefixed_path, storage)
  File "/home/gajeet/Documents/Django/Django_ultimate/dev2/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 368, in copy_file
    if not self.delete_file(path, prefixed_path, source_storage):
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/gajeet/Documents/Django/Django_ultimate/dev2/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 278, in delete_file
    if self.storage.exists(prefixed_path):
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/gajeet/Documents/Django/Django_ultimate/dev2/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/storages/backends/s3.py", line 514, in exists
    self.connection.meta.client.head_object(Bucket=self.bucket_name, Key=name)
  File "/home/gajeet/Documents/Django/Django_ultimate/dev2/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 553, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/gajeet/Documents/Django/Django_ultimate/dev2/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 1009, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden
```

Comment: Can you also add this resource: `arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>` and re-try?

Comment: I tried it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the permissions to list the bucket, which could be required to validate your bucket access, add the below statement in the above policy to resolve your issue:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement":
    [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket_name>/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:List*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket_name>",
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: My bucket policy I mentioned above has all the s3 actions denoted by the *

However I also tried this adding separately but it didnt help :(

Comment: @GAjeet the updated policy in the answer could resolve your issue

Comment: I just tried it, still gives the same error.

Comment: Then it could be iam user credentials issue, may be other policies attached to the user impacting this?